# how can i modify 3 chanenls train image to 4channels in mmdetection?

Tags: python

I want to train 4channels image in mmdetection. But I don't know how to modify codes.

How can I do this?

First, I tried to modify **call** function in class LoadImageFromFile in mmdetection/mmdet/datasets/pipelines/loading.py, but I got error.

```
    def __call__(self, results):

        ......

        results['filename'] = filename
        results['ori_filename'] = results['img_info']['filename']
        results['img'] = img
        results['img_shape'] = img.shape
        results['ori_shape'] = img.shape
        results['img_fields'] = ['img']
        return results
```

Second, I tried to modify **getitem** function in class CustomDatset in mmdetection/mmdet/datasets/custom.py

```
        if self.test_mode:
            return self.prepare_test_img(idx)
        while True:
            data = self.prepare_train_img(idx)
            if data is None:
                idx = self._rand_another(idx)
                continue
            return data
```

I modified data['img'] to custom image, but I failed.

Comment: What error did you get in `LoadImageFromFile`? Also most of the transforms in mmdetection expect a 3 channel image, so you will have to modify them as well. Post the updates you made along with the error you got please.